# How to use RxJS Observable way to select a DIV?

Tags: typescript, angular, rxjs, rxjs5

I am using Angular 2.

Right now I know this way to select a DIV item:

```
<div #aaa>
</div>

@ViewChild('aaa') private aaa: ElementRef;
ngAfterViewInit() {
  let item = this.aaa.nativeElement;
  item.style.top = '10px';
}
```

Is there a RxJS Observable way to select that item, then do something like `item.style.top = '10px';`? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
<div [style.top.px]="someProp"></div>

someMethod() {
  this.someProp = 10;
}
```

Comment: @HongboMiao this is certainly a better solution than mine if your use case is actually as simple as what you've posted (I had assumed what you posted was a simplified version).

Comment: I also assumed that the example in the question is simplified, but IMHO before going the `elementRef.xxx` route one should be sure ;-)

Comment: Agree completely - I almost added a comment to the effect of "you should really be using Renderer to do this" in the code, but decided it was beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: thanks @GünterZöchbauer! This is definitely an clean way. BTW seems they may add a @ObserveChild [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4062) in the future

Answer (score 2):

If you use [`@ViewChildren()`](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/ViewChildren-var.html) rather than `@ViewChild()`, you'll get a [`QueryList<T>`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/QueryList-class.html) object, which has a `changes` field that is an `Observable<T>`.

```
@ViewChildren('aaa') private aaa: QueryList<ElementRef>; 
...
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.aaa.changes.subscribe(elementRef => elementRef.nativeElement.style.top = '10px');
}
```

Comment: thanks for help!! And seems they may add a @ObserveChild [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4062) in the future